# Is there a better way instead of using multiple UNION ALL queries in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, union

I want to run the same select query but change only the `romecode` field which is a string and limit each result by 30. Finally, I concatenate all the results into one usingUNION ALL.

This is the full list of codes which means that I need to repeat the same select + UNION ALL many times:

```
('G1603', 'E1205', 'D1101', 'N1202', 'M1501', 'G1402', 'I1401',
'M1607', 'J1102', 'C1201', 'M1801', 'I1203', 'I1604', 'M1705',
'H2102', 'M1203', 'K2503', 'E1103', 'N1103', 'M1805', 'H1204',
'M1602', 'D1106', 'M1707', 'C1501', 'M1701', 'G1101', 'J1302',
'C1103', 'E1401', 'J1201', 'H1301', 'C1301')
```

And how I am doing now:

```
(
        SELECT
        appellationlibelle,
        romelibelle,
        romecode,
        descriptioncleaned,
        description
      FROM
        `scrappers-293910.vigilant_memory_raw.indeed` 
      WHERE romecode = 'G1603' LIMIT 30)

      UNION ALL
(
      SELECT
        appellationlibelle,
        romelibelle,
        romecode,
        descriptioncleaned,
        description
      FROM
        `scrappers-293910.vigilant_memory_raw.indeed` 
      WHERE romecode = 'E1205' LIMIT 30)

      UNION ALL
(
      SELECT
        appellationlibelle,
        romelibelle,
        romecode,
        descriptioncleaned,
        description
      FROM
        `scrappers-293910.vigilant_memory_raw.indeed` 
      WHERE romecode = 'D1101' LIMIT 30)
```

I repeat this select 33 times.
I tried to find a similar solution but I couldn't find any. If it is a duplicated question just kindly drop the link please :D

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh Google Big Query which uses Google Standard SQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combine into a single query, use Row_number() to give each row a number resetting on each Romecode.  Then bring back all rows where the row number is 30 or below.

You just need to clarify how you choose which 30 rows to bring back.  Your original query doesn't specify so you'll need to figure that out to plug into the row_number order by.

```
select
*
from
(
    SELECT
        appellationlibelle,
        romelibelle,
        romecode,
        descriptioncleaned,
        description,
        row_number() over (partition by romecode order by datecreation) as rn
      FROM
        scrappers-293910.vigilant_memory_raw.indeed
      WHERE romecode in
      ('G1603', 'E1205', 'D1101', 'N1202', 'M1501', 'G1402', 'I1401',
'M1607', 'J1102', 'C1201', 'M1801', 'I1203', 'I1604', 'M1705',
'H2102', 'M1203', 'K2503', 'E1103', 'N1103', 'M1805', 'H1204',
'M1602', 'D1106', 'M1707', 'C1501', 'M1701', 'G1101', 'J1302',
'C1103', 'E1401', 'J1201', 'H1301', 'C1301')
) thedata where thedata.rn <= 30
```

Comment: I want the first 30 results for each romecode.

Comment: Yes, I get that, but how can you tell which are the first 30?  LIMIT is random unless you specify an ORDER BY which you didn't.  Your original query could change which 30 you get back.  Do you have an ID or date field that tells you explicitly the order that the records were entered?

Comment: You're right. I have a  ´datecreation´ field which one can use to ORDER BY.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer using the DateCreation in the Row_Number order by.  That will bring you back the first 30 rows for each of the listed Romecodes without doing a UNION, in a single query.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks ! I will try to learn this now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've misunderstood your question, but this seems easy to do with an IN (...) condition.

```
SELECT
        appellationlibelle,
        romelibelle,
        romecode,
        descriptioncleaned,
        description
      FROM
        `scrappers-293910.vigilant_memory_raw.indeed` 
      WHERE romecode in ('G1603', 'E1205', 'D1101', 'N1202', 'M1501', 'G1402', 'I1401',
'M1607', 'J1102', 'C1201', 'M1801', 'I1203', 'I1604', 'M1705',
'H2102', 'M1203', 'K2503', 'E1103', 'N1103', 'M1805', 'H1204',
'M1602', 'D1106', 'M1707', 'C1501', 'M1701', 'G1101', 'J1302',
'C1103', 'E1401', 'J1201', 'H1301', 'C1301')

-- LIMIT 30 <-- don't know if you still want this?
```

Comment: I think that he wanted to list 30 results for each of those codes.

Comment: The problem is that I need 30 results for each romecode. In this statement, I will have the first 30 results only which will return results only for the first romecode.

Comment: Aaah, sorry, I overlooked that requirement.